# jQuery++, problems on .selection()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery++

everybody.
I have a little problem; I'm trying to build a WYSIWYG, but I encountered some problems.
I have a contenteditable div with id = desc2, and some buttons. Let's take, for example, the button "bold".

```
<div class="magic" magic_id="desc2">
    <div class="magicbutton one" magic="[b]%s[/b]">
        <span style="font-weight:bold;">Bold</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have some jQuery++ selection application in:

```
$('#desc2').on('mouseup', function() {
    var selection = $(this).selection(),
        text = $(this).text().substring(selection.start, selection.end);
    console.log(text);
});
```

I have erased the other part of the script, because if I manage to get this to work, I'm done :D
So, as I was saying, if I do this, everything is good: I sleect a part on the div and on the console is outputted the content.
But this is not what I want to do. I wrote this:

```
$('.magicbutton.uno').on('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).parent().attr("magic_id");
    var selection = $("#"+id).selection(),
    text = $("#"+id).text().substring(selection.start, selection.end);
    console.log(text);
});
```

Everytime I click, it takes the ID of the div to change and should output the selected text, but it doesn't.
The code is the same, and i checked that `$(this)` in the first script is the same as `$("#"+id)` in the second.

What can I do? Thanks!

EDIT: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4BB6f/1)

Comment: If you click oustide input/textarea (or what???), doesn't the selection get loose? Maybe you could provide a jsFiddle to make your question clearer because here you are using some selector without letting us see any relevant HTML markup, e.g, what is `"#"+id` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When DIV loses focus, selection is nullified. As a workaround, you could use data object:

### DEMO

```
$('.magicbutton.one').on('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).parent().attr("magic_id"); //id = desc2, i used this because i could have multiple forms in a page
    var selection = $("#"+id).data('selection');
    alert(selection);
}); //This doesn't work

$('#desc2').on('mouseup', function() {
    var selection = $(this).selection(),
        text = $(this).text().substring(selection.start, selection.end);
    $(this).data('selection', text);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, this works, but I wanted to avoid using the mouseup event, all I was asking was why mouseup works and click with the same code doesn't.
EDIT: Oh, I understand now, it's because of the osing of focus... I'll manage to find a way to mantain the focus w/out using the mouseup. Thanks!!